# How to write a program that print bits of integer in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary

How to write a program that print out bits of integer.
I'm trying to do something like that:

```
    function    countBits(octet)
    {
        var     i;
        var     c = "";
        var k = "";
        i = 128;

        while (i > 0)
        {
            c = "";
            if (octet < i)
            {
                c = '0';
                i = i / 2;
                k += c
            }
            else
            {
                c = '1';
                k += c
                octet = octet - i;
                i = i / 2;
            }
        }
      return k;
}
```

But if I trying to print bits with this program I have Output:

```
Input: 123
Output 01111011 and infinity numbers of zero
```

How can I remove this bug?

P.S: I want to do this program using only loops and algorithms, NOT function like `(n >>> 0).toString(2);` or `.map()` or something like this

Comment: I'm not sure why `c` is needed. Can't you just `+=` the string literal?

Comment: Yes, but is more comfortable for me :)

Comment: Really? Your code is pretty cryptic right now. Other than `octet` none of the variables make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i added a little logging for checking the values of i and I got this in the loop:
i = 64; i = 32; i = 16; ... i = 1; i = 0.5; i = 0.25

So yeah, do what AgataB said with regards to using another condition instead since for javascript, 
1 / 2 does not give you 0.

> Unlike many other programming languages, JavaScript does not define
>   different types of numbers, like integers, short, long, floating-point
>   etc.
>
> JavaScript numbers are always stored as double precision floating
>   point numbers, following the international IEEE 754 standard.

Quoted from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Comment: But now, when I put numbers bigger than 250, I always have output:
`11111111`

Comment: Well, because your i is 128. So regardless of what, the maximum will always be at 255, i.e. 11111111 since by then, 128 will reach 0.5. And that is why its called octet i.e. a byte, with at most 8 bits.

Answer (score 4):

Your variable `i` is always greater than 0, so the while loop keeps running forever. When you decrement it, you halve it. That will never get to 0, however it will get to a value smaller than one, and at this point you want to stop.

Try using `while (i >= 1)` instead as your condition.